# Show <A id> Inside placeholder in form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show my `<A id>` inside a form inside html.

Like this

```
 <input name="indsendte" value="<a id="indsendt"></a>" class="indsendte">
```

The reason im trying to do this is because i have a javascript function, that looks like this.

```
var indsendt = 0;
 function indsend() {
 indsendt += 1;
 document.getElementById("indsendt").innerHTML = indsendt;
 }
```

So basically i am trying to display the variable inside my form. Is this in anyway possible?

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason of using <a> inside input tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you wont to show the value of the variable 'indsendt' in your input, this is the way:

```
      var indsendt = 0;
         function indsend() {
         indsendt += 1;
         document.getElementById("indsendt").innerHTML = indsendt;
         // here is the new line of code
         document.getElementsByName("indsendte")[0].value = indsendt;
         }
```

Look this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fb31sfz6/1/)